# How to make payments to azure?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service

I have subscribed for free account and now its expired so i m tried to make payment to  "Pay-As-You-Go" subscription and in Summary for "Pay-As-You-Go", its showing me an balance amount , subscription ID and order ID but its not showing any links to make a payment.
         my credit card details are also there. now my web application and db have stopped and i cannot reactivate it.  please help. 
    I already tried buying a gift card and use the redeem code even not possible.

Thank You

Comment: Welcome to SO! I don't think you'll find an answer here for this particular problem of yours. From Azure Portal, you can open up a billing support request and Azure support team should be able to help you out.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a customer support / billing issue, and not a programming issue.

Answer (score 1):

Please create a support ticket using below steps:

1.Go to the Azure Support web site and click Get Support. You can also submit an incident from the Microsoft Azure portal or from the Azure Accounts Center.

•To submit a support ticket from the Azure portal, click your account name, and then click Contact Microsoft Support.
•To submit a support ticket from the Azure Account Center, select a subscription, and then click Contact Microsoft Support.

2.In the Create Support Ticket window, select the subscription for which you want to migrate data and services.

3.For Support Type, choose Billing.

4.Select your region and language, and then click Create Ticket.

5.On the next page, for Problem Type, select My Subscription is Displayed as Disabled. If you need assistance with submitting your support ticket, click Chat with customer service to initiate a live conversation with a customer service representative.

6.Confirm your contact information, provide a telephone number at which you can be reached, and then click Continue.

7.On the next page, provide the following information:

•For Problem Details, provide an incident title for your request and then use the text boxes provide required information and to include any additional information about your request.

•For Determine Severity, choose an option that represents the severity of your request. For more information about the severity types, refer to the Microsoft Azure Incident Severity Table.

•Use the File Upload tool to attach related documentation to your request.

8.If you accept the Agreement for Microsoft Services, click Submit.

You will be contacted by an Azure Support representative in accordance with the terms of the agreement.

Comment: Thank you very much